How to auto-refresh, auto-update, and publish workbook tableau desktop
I had connected my data using Xamp and my database is conncted to Tablue desktop I published my graph on the Tablue server and saved my workbookand displayed that data on our website but when I made changes in my database or added new data in my data sheet, data didn't get auto reflected on my table well In my website I have to auto-refresh and auto-update manually I want a solution how can I auto-publish and auto-update my data from database.
i have to do it manually everytime. i want to do it by itself or any other thing that should work.

I'm sorry, but this question has nothing to do with progtamming or software development, therefore it is off topic here on SO. Please ask your question on Tableau's support site!
